# JQuery - Hide the first instance of button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide the first instance of a button(close symbol Refer screenshot) dynamically. i.e. I am creating divs which consists of the button by using a javascript function which I am calling on click. I want to hide the first instance of the button. Tried using the jquery :first selector but when I add div using the on click method the button disappears for the second instance as well. What should I do so that only the first instance of close button is hidden?

[image: Without applying jquery; want to hide the close button for the first instance]

[image: Works fine when applied jquery. The first instance gets hidden]

[image: When div is created using add button, the close button disappears for the second instance as well. Want to stop this]

my JQuery code:

```
$("#box button:first").hide();
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="box" class="box-body" role="dynamic-fields">
<div class="inline-form" id="inline-form">
    <div id="clone" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="" for="inputPackageName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    Package Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPackageName" placeholder="Package Name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="sample" class="form-group">
                <label style="margin-left: -8%;" for="inputApplicationName" class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 control-label">
                    Application Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApplicationName" placeholder="Package Name">
                </div>
                <button id="btn-close" class="btn btn-box-tool">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your html there is only 1 button element

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the hidden close buttons to be visible again if you add a new div?

Comment: Be aware that `id` **must** be unique per document. You cannot have two elements that have the same `id` value. So you can use and of your `id` values only *once** per document, e.g. `#box`, `#sample`, `#inline-form`, `#clone`. You're probably over- and misusing `id`.

Comment: @guradio There is only button in the current div, the other button will be generated dynamically when the user clicks on add button. Refer the screenshot.

Comment: Looking at your sample I would guess you have duplicate IDs in your page. That will never work with jQuery as it only finds the first match.

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez exactly ! Just want the close buttons to be visible when user adds another div by clicking on add button. The close button shouldn't be visible when there is only one div.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using specific `id` values more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a custom class to your close buttons, like this:

```
<button id="btn-close" class="btn btn-box-tool closebutton">
     <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
```

and then do something like:

```
$(".closebutton").show();
$(".closebutton:first").hide();
```

This will show all close buttons except the first one. Just execute that code every time you add or remove a div.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Worked out for me.. except that had to call the hide() method once more before the add div method so that the close button is not visible when there is only single div.

Comment: This fails to address the duplicate `id` problem. Even the `button` has the `id="btn-close"` which OP probably repeats in every `.box-body`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique id sample

you can do the following:

```
$('#sample').find('button').hide();
```

or select based on the first `#clone` element

```
$('.inline-form row:first-child').find('button').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your scope selector

```
$(".form-group:first button:first").hide();
```

This will work for the first button  inside the first `form-group` classed divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".box-body").find("button:first").hide();
```

Comment: No different to the original. The most likely cause is duplicate IDs in the page (which will not match correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this. It uses class of the button to handle the *click* event.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/eLcv86pa/1/)

```
$(".btn-box-tool").click(function() {
  $("#box button:first").hide();
});
```